# PHP Rand but dont allow specific numbers above or below

Tags: php, random

Good day,

Iam trying to use the PHP Rand function, works great but I want to specify it more. Current code that works:

```
$min=100;
$max=500;
$random=rand($min,$max);
echo $random;
```

What I want it todo is that each number generated must have more than 10 difference with any other generated number.
For example it generates the following:

- 110 (1st generated)
- 116 (No)
- 101 (No)
- 90 (Yes)
- 100 (No)
- 120 (Yes)
- 103 (No)

And so forth

Does rand allow itself to be manipulated?

Comment: Not without a bit of your code to keep track of the previous random number, and test to see if it's in that range

Comment: I am going to store the numbers in a database, they all have to be unique and have to be at least (somenumber) greater or lower then any other number present. Was just interested if rand could do this with some provided sql data. Or that I have todo this during a query while trying to insert or checking. #SQL Between

Comment: If the valid range is 100-500, and they must all be at least 10 apart, then you won't be generating many values before you start getting duplications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round the numbers to multiples of 11, like so:

```
$random = floor(rand($min, $max) / 11) * 11;
```

And keep track of the generated numbers in an array so that you don't get the same one twice.

Any two different multiples of 11 have at least 11 difference.

Comment: Thank you, the tweakalike is was looking for.